# Make the width of an element be of the same width of another corresponding element with the largest width?

Tags: html, css

here is a Fiddle I've made:

https://jsfiddle.net/cjtvvwrq/2/

Here is the HTML and CSS of the fiddle:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<table id="outerTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Monday</th>
      <th colspan="2">Tuesday</th>
      <th colspan="2">Wednesday</th>
      <th colspan="2">Thursday</th>
      <th colspan="2">Friday</th>
      <th colspan="2">Saturday</th>
      <th colspan="2">Sunday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="thead-cell" colspan="2">
        <table style="width: 100%;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Morning</td>
              <td>Afternoon</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th class="thead-cell" colspan="2">
        <table style="width: 100%;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Morning</td>
              <td>Afternoon</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th class="thead-cell" colspan="2">
        <table style="width: 100%;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Morning</td>
              <td>Afternoon</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th class="thead-cell" colspan="2">
        <table style="width: 100%;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Morning</td>
              <td>Afternoon</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th class="thead-cell" colspan="2">
        <table style="width: 100%;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Morning</td>
              <td>Afternoon</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th class="thead-cell" colspan="2">
        <table style="width: 100%;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Morning</td>
              <td>Afternoon</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th class="thead-cell" colspan="2">
        <table style="width: 100%;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Morning</td>
              <td>Afternoon</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="padding: 2px; background-color: #006CCC" class="cell">
        <div class="" style="padding: 0">
          <table class="cell-table" style="table-layout: fixed;">
            <tbody>
              <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
     </td>
      <td colspan="2" style="padding: 2px; background-color: #006CCC" class="cell">
        <div class="" style="padding: 0">
          <table class="cell-table" style="table-layout: fixed;">
            <tbody>
              <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT </div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
     </td>     
      <td colspan="2" style="padding: 2px; background-color: #006CCC" class="cell">
        <div class="" style="padding: 0">
          <table class="cell-table" style="table-layout: fixed;">
            <tbody>
              <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
     </td>
      <td colspan="2" style="padding: 2px; background-color: #006CCC" class="cell">
        <div class="" style="padding: 0">
          <table class="cell-table" style="table-layout: fixed;">
            <tbody>
              <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
     </td>
      <td colspan="2" style="padding: 2px; background-color: #006CCC" class="cell">
        <div class="" style="padding: 0">
          <table class="cell-table" style="table-layout: fixed;">
            <tbody>
              <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT </div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
     </td>
      <td colspan="2" style="padding: 2px; background-color: #006CCC" class="cell">
        <div class="" style="padding: 0">
          <table class="cell-table" style="table-layout: fixed;">
            <tbody>
              <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT </div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
     </td>     
      <td colspan="2" style="padding: 2px; background-color: #006CCC" class="cell">
        <div class="" style="padding: 0">
          <table class="cell-table" style="table-layout: fixed;">
            <tbody>
              <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="team-cell">
                  <div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
     </td>     
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

#container {
  padding: 15px;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

#outerTable {
  margin: 0 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
}

.thead-cell {
  padding: 0;
}

.thead-cell td {
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.thead-cell tr td:first-child {
  border-left-color: transparent;
}

.badge {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #f89406;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: 1px solid #8E6B2A;
    font-size: 11px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I have used some nested tables because I thought it would work, but maybe the HTML structure should change anyway.

Basically what I want is to have the `Morning` and `Afternoon` cells of each day to have always the width of the widest `td.team-cell` within the corresponding side (right for `Afternoon`, left for `Morning`) day of the week.

If you look for example at `Monday`, the widest team cell is the second one on the right, then I would like `Afternoon` to be of the same width in order to keep the `thead` sync with the `tbody`.

I would like it to look somehow like this (I have padded `Afternoon` with some `&nbsp;`, of course this is not a solution):

[image]

What is the best known approach, best practice in such situations?

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want cells have the same width over rows, then you should avoid using a nested table in each row.
Why already tried to use colspan (for the week days it makes sense). But the rest of the approach doesn't make any sense. Get rid of the nested tables - it's all possible with only one table and all data in just plain table cells.

Think you can do it yourself? Or should I help you with your dom structure?

Just as impression: https://jsfiddle.net/cjtvvwrq/7/

```
<div id="container">
    <table id="outerTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Monday</th>
                <th colspan="2">Tuesday</th>
                <th colspan="2">Wednesday</th>
                <th colspan="2">Thursday</th>
                <th colspan="2">Friday</th>
                <th colspan="2">Saturday</th>
                <th colspan="2">Sunday</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Morning</td>
                <td>Afternoon</td>
                <td>Morning</td>
                <td>Afternoon</td>
                <td>Morning</td>
                <td>Afternoon</td>
                <td>Morning</td>
                <td>Afternoon</td>
                <td>Morning</td>
                <td>Afternoon</td>
                <td>Morning</td>
                <td>Afternoon</td>
                <td>Morning</td>
                <td>Afternoon</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-cell">
                        <div class="badge">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="badge">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </td>            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And try to avoid inline-styling and do it via classes and in seperate css-block/file.

Comment: Well, I will be grateful if you can give me some help with this! Previously I used one `div` instead of a table and I didn't use the `colspan="2"` attribute for the `td`s, but the point is that the `.team-cell` sometimes should take the full width of `Morning` and `Afternoon` and sometimes it could only take the width of `Morning` or `Afternoon`, that's why I tried to use one cell with `colspan="2"`

Comment: If then there is a data-cell (TD) which should make up the width of both morning AND afternoon you can use `colspan="2"` again. (I added one for friday in my example.)

Comment: That's great! The only thing is, how can I say that the first `div.team-cell` (and not its `td` container) of the `Monday` `Morning` cell should occupy the `Afternoon` cell too?

Comment: Then you need to split those in seperate rows.
By the way there is a `rowspan` attribute as well, if  you have rows with fewer cells than others. Just apply it on a td which should make up more than one row (define the number of rows as parameter as you would do for `colspan`).

Comment: Thanks, I will try what you mean, but still I haven't understand how to proceed completely.

Comment: Your main issue seems to be that you think in columns. In HTML you have to think more in rows first. You kind of split a cell using a new table, which is not a good way to do and which is not working for what you want to accomplish visually. You have to think of the smallest cell first, an every larger cell in the same row or column will need a colspan or rowspan.

If I could help you, you are free to accept it as the answer.  ;)